# Switch to different filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, quota

I am relatively new to linux, but am working on a remote server. It says i have a quota, and shows the following

```
 Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
  /dev/sda7 4756320* 4194304 5242880   02:51   72897       0       0
  /dev/sda8      48  41943040 52428800              88       0       0
```

This seems to me that sda7 is full, but sda8 is not. How can i switch to sda8? I tried cd /dev/sda8, but it says: Not a directory.

Comment: Run `df -h` to see if the partitions are mounted anywhere. If they are, then you can `cd` into the mount points.

Comment: Please provide output of "df -h" and  "sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda" and a bit about your use case.   You can't switch to /dev/sda8 - but you may be able to graft it onto a heavily used spot, or delete sda8 and expand the partition size of sda7 to include its space.

Comment: Thanks both! I think i just have some misunderstanding of how linux works in general. I thought it was more like windows `C:` and `D:`. Anyway, `df -h` solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if you already have a mount created for this by running `df -h`. If not then continue

You cannot change directories because it is not a directory. /dev/sd* is simply the representation of SCSI partitions on your storage device.

Before you can use this you need to do the following if this partition has not had a filesystem created for it. This assumes you are wanting to access this partition to store other data on rather than resizing current partition

```
mkfs.ext4 -L /dev/sda8
mkdir /mnt/*directory*
mount /dev/sda8 /mnt/*directory*
```

This makes your partition usable by creating a filesystem for it and then mounting it so you are now able to `cd` into the `/mnt` directory you created.

If you want to reallocate your system partition that will need to be done on a live USB or CD as you should not modify the partition you are currently running on.

Comment: There may already be a filesystem created and he just needs to see where it is mounted.

Comment: @NasirRiley good point. Should have got more clarification before submitting

Comment: Being assigned a quota very strongly suggests that the OP is not in a position to mount anything.

Comment: @user2994884 As the quota is on the partition itself, it would have to be specified in the `/etc/fstab` file so that it takes effect at mount when the system starts up. With that being said, it's safe to say that the partition has a mount point that he can `cd` into.

Comment: @user2994884 Thank you for your answer. The top part was all i needed, there was already a mount for it and i could find it with `df -h` .